# Multiple magento stores on single domain

Tags: magento

I'm setting up a website that has a retail store and a wholesalers store. The products in each are different so its not just a matter of adjusting pricing for user types. I need to have the wholesale section password protected so its only available to logged in users. I'm using a module to achieve this but it only works at a store level hence the need for two stores rather than just separate categories.

My directory structure is as follows:

www.mysite.com - wordpress install for current CMS pages and blog etc
www.mysite.com/store - magento install

I want www.mysite.com/store/retail & www.mysite.com/store/wholesale as the two shops.

So my question - firstly does this sound like <strike>the right</strike> a reasonable approach to achieve this.

Secondly - still trying to get my head around the website/store/view system but am I correct in that I need the one website, and two stores with a view for each. Does anyone know of a good tutorial for doing this sort of setup, I've found a few but mostly they're for setting up different domains to the same install.

Thanks for any advise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest way (and most used) is to give the two stores the store codes "retail" and "wholesale". This is done in the admin menu *System > Manage Stores*.

Then, in *System > Configuration > Web > URL Options*, change *Add Store Code to URLs* to "Yes".

Since the two stores have separate products, and probably separate customers too then it makes more sense to have them on two separate websites too. Even though they are called "websites" in *System > Manage Stores* they do not have to have different domains. It will still work perfectly well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I'm using this tutorial: http://bit.ly/hksf2H with the option for subdirectories. So I should be setting these up as websites in the backend, creating a directory for each and then copying index.php and .htaccess and modifying accordingly? I've done that and having some issues so just want to make sure i'm on the right track before spending more time ironing this out. Thanks again for you advice.

Comment: Just the two steps is enough to get going, no need to actually create the directories. It works the same whether using stores or websites.