# How to create a different store in magento on single domain?

Tags: php, magento, nginx, magento-1.9

I am really searching hard to make a two different stores in magento with different functionalities and i believe that this is possible in magento with 2 different magento installation on single domain.

I have went through some of the following tutorials:

[Multiple magento stores on single domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319694/multiple-magento-stores-on-single-domain)

http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-set-multiple-websites-with-multiple-store-views-in-magento/

I have carefully read this tutorials, but i think this tutorials work for only on one magento installation.

I wanted to know whether we can make two store, like

1.www.domain.com/store1
 2.www.domain.com/store2

with different template design and different functionalities as well, so i think we will need 2 different installation.

Also my 1st website is already created and i want to share the categories and products ,but with different product prices on the 2nd store.

Are these things possible with magento and if yes then need a hint or little help ?

Also ,how can we change the nginx configuration for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to create different website views and stores views. This can be done in the System > Manage Stores.

Then you need to in the system >Configuration part their is a drop down and you can select the website view and set the theme and everything for that.

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes, but how can i give the different prices to the same products for different region? is there any plugin for that? Advanced Pricing,Zone pricing plugins are useless

Comment: @CoolD you want to create different store views for those regions, and then you need add custom code in the index.php to switch to those store views based on how you want the region to be detected. Each website view can have many different store views.

Comment: i am interested in knowing even if i create a different store on a single domain, how will i be able to give the different prices to the same products with different base currency and display on it store views? i want to share the same products and categories with the different store.

Comment: @CoolD yes this is exactly what a store view is made to do.

Comment: Hi @italiano40, I have created a new store and creating categories as well, but how to use the same products into new Root Category and Sub-category, Also need to change the products price as well because i have changed the base currency, is there any way ?